# Problem while displaying colors in JavaFX bar chart

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

In my project, I am using a `barchart` and a `linechart` in the same frame to display the same data. However, due to some reason, I am getting an output where there is no color in either the `barchart` or the `linechart`.

For example:
[image]
In this image, the `linechart` has color but the `barchart` doesn't.

The code that I used:

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="401.0" prefWidth="802.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" stylesheets="@stylesheet.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication26.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="1.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="303.0" prefWidth="801.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="46.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="342.0" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="244.0" prefWidth="419.0" style="-fx-border-color: #4E6172; -fx-background-color: white;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-2.0">
               <children>
                  <LineChart fx:id="linechart" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="11.0" prefHeight="353.0" prefWidth="380.0">
                    <xAxis>
                      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                      <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                    </yAxis>
                  </LineChart>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="8.0" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="392.0" style="-fx-border-color: #4E6172; -fx-background-color: white;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="399.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-2.0">
               <children>
                  <BarChart fx:id="barchart" layoutX="3.0" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="363.0" prefWidth="391.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
                    <xAxis>
                      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                      <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                    </yAxis>
                  </BarChart>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Java Controller:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javafxapplication26;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 *
 * @author param
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
  
    
    @FXML
    private LineChart<String, Number> linechart;
    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Number> barchart;
    
   
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         XYChart.Series<String, Number> series= new  XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
        series.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Jan",12));
        series.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Feb",20));
        series.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("March",10));
        series.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("April",14));
    
      
        linechart.getData().add(series);
        barchart.getData().add(series);
        
      
        // TODO
    }      
} 
}
```

As shown in the image, only one of either the `barchart` or the `linechart` is capable of displaying color. I tried using the `-fx-bar-fill` method, but even that didn't work.

Comment: You should create a new program from scratch that demonstrates the problem you're having. It should do nothing else. In your case, you might only need a `BarChart` and some mock data at a minimum; no `LineChart`, no FXML, no buttons, and so on (unless those things are _strictly_ needed to reproduce the problem). And we should be able to copy the code onto our machines and run it with very little to no modifications. The help page linked by kleopatra gives more details on how to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you @Slaw for your suggestions. I have included a mock program to what I am doing. Surprisingly, the colors are displayed in the mock program

Comment: So, it appears the problem could not be easily reproduced by creating a new program from scratch. Now try the other approach—reducing your actual code (possibly after making a copy of it, or a new branch if you're using source control). If removing something causes the problem to go away, then you've found the problematic code. Remove everything else not necessary for that problematic code to execute. Once you've narrowed this down, you might be able to solve the problem yourself. If not, replace your current [mre] with the new one (that actually demonstrates the problem).

Comment: And no, there's no rule that prevents you from having a `BarChart` and a `LineChart` in the same scene.

Comment: @Slaw, I tried removing the `line-graph` and seeing if having only the `bar-graph` works. It did and the `bar graph` got colored. But, when I re-added the `line graph`, the `line-graph` got colored and the `bar-graph` lost it's color.

Comment: You wouldn't perhaps be sharing the same `XYChart.Series` instance between the two charts, would you?

Comment: okay, then show a minimal example that has both line and bar chart (again mock the data) just a thought:  are you by any chance re-using the same series in both (which you shouldn't)?

Comment: unrelated: never-ever hard-code sizes/locations of nodes, instead use a suitable layout pane (which AnchorPane rarely is .. completely unrelated: wondering why we see so many examples using it? Is that the default in Scenebuilder?)

Comment: @Slaw and @kleopatra, As it turns out, I was using the same series. I solved the problem by declaring one more Series `series2` and that seems to have solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help. Shall I post your solution as an answer ?

Comment: @kleopatra, Yes, the default in Scene-Builder is an `Anchor-Pane`. Should I start using a `Layout-pane` instead of an `Anchor-pane` for my future applications ?

Comment: yeah, might be a good idea to post an answer - while the re-use might be considered a typo-like error, it's not entirely obvious (personally, never have seen the color-loss :) Not using SceneBuilder, so no idea what it offers as alternative - but then you want to learn all about layouts anyway, to make a good decision :)

Comment: You can add your own answer (this might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find one quickly). I would first [edit] your question to update your [mre] so that it actually demonstrates the problem though. In your answer, you should explain why the solution works. And it works because `XYChart.Series` and `XYChart.Data` both—mistakenly, in my opinion—supply the `Node` associated with them that's displayed in the graph. A `Node` can only show up in the scene graph once. This means every chart must have its own `Series` and `Data` instances in order to work properly.

Comment: @Slaw _mistakenly, in my opinion_ you are right, that's a clear design goof, breaking of the boundary between view and data

Comment: Thank you @kleopatra. I will read more into each of the layouts. Also, completely unrelated, but do you think that JavaFX is obsolete, and that I should switch to something else for front end design ?

Comment: "do you think that JavaFX is obsolete" -> no. "should switch to something else for front end design ?" -> no idea, that depends on you, your app, your users, your target devices, your environment, etc. (stuff nobody here would know enough about to advise you).  There are many options for creating UIs that fit different niches.

Comment: The JavaFX Chart API shows every sign of having been written by an unsupervised intern with a particularly bad hangover… If you need charts in more than a trivial way I’d strongly recommend at least considering rolling your own implementation.

Comment: @jewelsea Thank you for your response. So, if I am building desktop applications, then JavaFX is still relevant right ? Thing is, I am kind of new to this application development, so I don't want to be stuck learning something that is obsolete :P. Anyways, thank you for your suggestions !

Comment: @James_D, That's a good idea. I will do more learning about APIs and how to develop them so that I can make my own APIs, which hopefully don't result in errors like this xD.

Comment: This is all kind of off-topic discussion, but I would disagree on some points with James here.  The JavaFX charts are fine for basic dashboard work where you might want a quick bar chart with ten bars or a pie chart with 5 or 6 slices.  If you want something more involved though like real-time charting, intense financial, and detailed scientific charting the JavaFX chart API isn't probably a good fit (James would probably know more about that than me).

Comment: There are many alternate chart APIs if the JavaFX charts aren't a good fit for your app.  I would only suggest writing your own charting if you are very skilled, otherwise use a pre-existing library, perhaps JFreeChart for a Java-based library (it also bridges to JavaFX), but also consider something HTML based as there are numerous HTML charting APIs that you can render in a JavaFX WebView.  Anyway, there are plenty of options.

Comment: Regarding learning something obsolete, everything is obsolete eventually.  But there is a difference between obsolescence and niche technology.  Niche technology can survive for a long time before becoming obsolete, but not be widely used like mainstream technologies.  Alternate UI systems based on HTML or Native Mobile Apps are more mainstream than JavaFX,  so if you want to learn something mainstream that many people use, you may consider learning those technologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @kleopatra and @Slaw mentioned, the problem was that I was using a single `Series` for both the `barchart` and the `linechart`. This was the cause of the error.

The solution was to use two different `Series`, titled `series1` and `series2` for the `barchart` and the `linechart` respectively.

The corrected code:

```
package javafxapplication26;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 *
 * @author param
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
  
    
    @FXML
    private LineChart<String, Number> linechart;
    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Number> barchart;
    
   
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series= new  XYChart.Series<String, Number>(); //For the barchart
        series.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Jan",12));
        series.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Feb",20));
        series.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("March",10));
        series.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("April",14));
    
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2= new  XYChart.Series<String, Number>(); //For the linechart
        series2.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Jan",12));
        series2.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Feb",20));
        series2.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("March",10));
        series2.getData().add(new  XYChart.Data<String, Number>("April",14));
        
        
        barchart.getData().add(series);   
        linechart.getData().add(series2);

    }     
}
```

As @Slaw mentioned, the problem was that each `barchart` or `linechart` **needs** to have it's own `Series` and `Data`. This is because each `XYChart.Series` and `XYChart.Data` supply the `Node` associated with them, and this is what is displayed in the graph.

Corrected Output:

[image]

Comment: Just to elaborate: As I noted in another comment, a `Node` can only appear once in the scene graph. If you add a `Node` to a second parent, then it is quietly removed from its current parent first. So, in the problematic code, you first added the series/data to the `BarChart`. Everything is still okay. But then you added the **same** series/data to the `LineChart`, and that caused at least some of the series/data `Node`s to be removed from the `BarChart` and added to the `LineChart`.